# Determining the cardinality of a system of free generators for the fundamental group of $E$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-groups

This is exercise 3 from Munkres section 84.

Let $X$ be the wedge of two circles; let $p:E\rightarrow X$ be a covering map. The fundamental group of $E$ maps isomorphically under $p_\ast$ onto a subgroup $H$ of the fundamental group of $X$; the latter is free on two generators $\alpha$ and $\beta.$

(1) For each of the four covering spaces $E$ given in Exercise 2 of $\S 81$, determine the cardinality of a system of free generators for the fundamental group of $E$.

(2) For each of these covering spaces, find, in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, a system of free generators for the subgroup $H$ of the fundamental group of $X$.

Here is one of $E$ given in the exercise:
[image]

There are three more covering spaces but I will try to apply to other covering spaces after I learn how to do this one. Any help is greatly appreciated. Or any reference to similar questions is welcome.

Comment: The space $E$ you posted an image of is homotopy equivalent to the wedge of three circles, and by van Kampen its fundamental group is a free group on three generators. In this case use the generators $B_2$, $A_1*A_2$, $A_1*B_1* A_1^{-1}$, and Finding the image of $\pi_1(E)$ in $H$ depends on how the covering map is described: for each circle in $E$, look at which circle(s) in $X$ it wraps around under the covering map, and it should spell out a word in $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @William I got it. Thanks!